# Trying to display a list of contacts from an API using a gem but can only get a few fields to show up

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, hubspot

I'm trying to display a list of All Contacts from the HubSpot API (https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/get_contacts) in a table. I'm using the https://github.com/adimichele/hubspot-ruby gem which has been mostly helpful. I was able to get much of the information to display using the following code:

```
<div class ="container-fluid text-center">
<div class="row">
    <h1>Contacts</h1>
</div>
<br />

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Company</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>

        <% 
            (Hubspot::Contact.all).each do |contact|
            info = contact.properties
        %>
        <%= info %>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><%= info[:firstname] %></th>
                    <th scope="row"><%= info[:lastname] %></th>
                    <th scope="row"><%= info[:company] %></th>
                </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, by default the gem only displays 3 properties for the Contact. While the HubSpot API sends over more, like email, I'm having trouble picking and choosing which properties I want. I was able to successfully pick out the email property by it self:

```
 <tbody>

        <% 
            ( Hubspot::Contact.all({ property: 'email' }) ).each do |contact|
            info = contact.properties
        %>
        <%= info %>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><%= info[:firstname] %></th>
                    <th scope="row"><%= info[:lastname] %></th>
                    <th scope="row"><%= info[:company] %></th>
                    <th scope="row"><%= info[:email] %></th>
                </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

But then I can't figure out how to add more on-top of the email. For example I'm getting syntax errors on :

```
( Hubspot::Contact.all({ property: 'email', 'firstname' }) ).each do
```

and

```
( Hubspot::Contact.all({ property: 'email'})({ property: 'firstname'}) ).each do
```

I considered scrapping all this and starting with a new gem. But the only other one that looks worth its wait (https://github.com/HubSpot/rHAPI) won't install properly. So I'm trying to get this first solution to work.

*Thank you* for any help. I'm teaching myself and have never posted on here before. I'm pretty nervous to post here, so any feedback on this issue or my code in general would mean the world to me.

Comment: Have you tried `{ property: ['email', 'firstname'] }` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Hubspot::Contact.all.each do |contact|
```

Then you're grabbing the whole object and you can get the pieces you need to build your table, assuming the keys you need are in the object that comes back from Hubspot.

I'm not familiar with that gem, but dropping values doesn't seem like a normal thing. If the key is not available in the .all.each then it's unlikely to be available using filters.

I had a quick look at the gem's lib, and couldn't see anything that would tell me that it would drop data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! The solution was:

```
{ property: ['email', 'firstname'] }
```